# How to cleanly get the path to the bash history?

Tags: rust

So, now and then i am looking into Rust, and this time i have the simple task to get the path to my bash history file.
So, you come up with env::var() and env::home_dir() and like to join them.
Now, it's like 1 or 2 lines in python and probably in C, i came up with this hideous 3 liner:

> ```
> let h_file = env::var("HISTFILE").unwrap_or(OsString::from_string(".bash_history".to_string())).into_string().unwrap_or_else(|_| { panic!("the end is near!!!")});
> let h_dir = env::home_dir().unwrap_or_else(|| { panic!("unable to get homedir!") } );
> let h_file_p = h_dir.join(h_file);
> ```

What would be the better way? To be honest, i am concerned that, as a beginner, just using the docs, i came up with is this hideous thing.

Edit: Of course the point is that the first line is that long, and i am aware that i could put all those commands in several lines following each other or use a gazillion match statements, all of which would not really make this a nice solution for a basic task..

Comment: How much do you care about errors? I think a lot of this code is dealing with error handling, and I feel that people are going to be surprised with how many errors are possible with code when they start programming in Rust...

Comment: The previous version was much smaller... https://github.com/buster/rrun/commit/d65bdffadb8391ac3f9adb648e617e2f20aea809#diff-93d0fcbc95e775bf2e023879c10a69e1R7
So most of this is due to OsString and what not.. So, apparently the old version is not working anymore and the new one is even uglier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are suffering because of the transition between `std::old_path` and `std::path`, namely on the return value of `home_dir()`. Once it returns a `std::path::PathBuf`, it will look like:

```
#![feature(os,env,path)]

use std::env;
use std::ffi::OsString;
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn future_home_dir() -> Option<PathBuf> {
    Some(PathBuf::new("/home/user"))
}

fn main() {
    let filename = env::var_os("HISTFILE").unwrap_or(OsString::from_str(".bash_history"));
    let home_dir = future_home_dir().expect("could not determine a home directory");
    let path = home_dir.join(&filename);

    println!("{:?}", path);
}
```

The stable version of this is:

```
use std::env;
use std::ffi::OsString;

fn main() {
    let filename = env::var_os("HISTFILE").unwrap_or_else(|| OsString::from(".bash_history"));
    let home_dir = env::home_dir().expect("could not determine a home directory");
    let path = home_dir.join(&filename);

    println!("{:?}", path);
}
```